# Get coordinates of a specific point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there anyway to actually pinpoint the point at `Y = 40,000` and see the X value there? I can never see that X value properly, as when I place the curser on the line `Y=40,000` it shows me coordinates for `Y=40,001`. [image: ![enter image description here]

Here I am actually clicking on the point at 40,000, but it is showing the point below. So, do I type something in the table on the left hand side to see what that point is?

Comment: Just to clarify - your question is about using Desmos? It's not actually a math question?

Comment: Also, to choose a point you'd need to specify an x-coordinate also.

Comment: I assume to find a y value in terms of x, there is a universal model to input into the calculator. @mweiss

Comment: @mweiss Yeah, I am trying to find what the X point would be, given the Y value.

Comment: For what function? Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @mweiss It shows the function in the screen shot. `y_1 ~  ab^{x_1}`

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your question now.

Comment: @mweiss Great. Feel free to post an answer also :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function of the form
$$y=ab^x$$
and you want to find the $x$-coordinate that matches a specific $y$-value, you can use logarithms to solve for $x$.

For example, to solve
$$40000=ab^x$$
you would proceed as follows:
$$\frac{40000}{a}=b^x$$
$$\ln \left( \frac{40000}{a} \right) = x\ln b$$
$$x = \frac{1}{\ln b} \ln \left( \frac{40000}{a} \right)$$

Plug in your values of $a$ and $b$ and you should be able to compute $x$.

**However**, in your situation you only have *approximate* values for $a$ and $b$, found by fitting an exponential curve through three points that do not actually lie on an exponential curve.  So expecting exact solutions in this situation isn't very realistic.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=a b^x$, then $\log y = \log a + \log(b^x) = \log a + x \log b$.

Isolating $x$ gives $x = \frac{ \log y - \log a}{\log b} = \frac{ \log \frac{y}{a}}{\log b}$.